# SHA256 on Terminal vs. Node.js giving two different hashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, terminal, cryptography

I want to get a SHA256 Hash that gives me the same result as I get on the terminal

`echo -n "hello world" | shasum -0 -a 256`

`e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`

I tried two different scripts

```
const {Sha256} = require('@aws-crypto/sha256-js');

(async () => {
    const hash = new Sha256();
    hash.update('hello world');
    const result = await hash.digest();
    let hex = Buffer.from(result).toString('hex');
    console.log(hex);
})()
```

And

```
var hash = require('hash.js')

console.log(hash.sha256().update('hello world').digest('hex'))
```

They both give me the hash `b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9`

How can I get the same hash from the `shasum` in my terminal?

Comment: -0 denotes the BITS mode, i.e. 0 and 1 are interpreted as 0-bit and 1-bit, all other characters are ignored. Since there are no 0 and 1 values in _hello world_, the SHA256 hash of an empty string / empty byte sequence is produced: 0xe3...55, s. [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=SHA2('256',64,160)). In contrast, 0xb9...e9 is the SHA256 hash value of the ASCII encoding of _hello world_.

Comment: @Topaco that is an answer not a comment...

Comment: Neither of the two JavaScript/NodeJS libraries nor the crypto module of NodeJS support hashing of bit sequences afaik, unless they are byte sequences (i.e. the number of bits is divisible by 8 so that the bit sequence can be converted to a byte sequence). Simply padding an incomplete bit sequence to the next full byte with 0 bits doesn't work (see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/zbAYnPZ7X)) because of the way SHA256 works (see [here](https://qvault.io/cryptography/how-sha-2-works-step-by-step-sha-256/)).

Answer (score 1):

If you ask the man page of shasum you will see;

> ```
> -0, --01          read in BITS mode
>                            ASCII '0' interpreted as 0-bit,
>                            ASCII '1' interpreted as 1-bit,
>                            all other characters ignored
> ```

That reads only `0`s and `1`s from the file ( pipe in your case).  Now remove the parameter `-0` or better define the default

> -t, --text        read in text mode (default)

> $ echo -n "hello world" | shasum -t -a 256 | cut -c -64
> b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9

Now we have the same output.

**Note 1**: that the `cut` is used to remove the space and dash in the end.

**Not 2 :** NIST has test vector in [Cryptographic Algorithm Validation Program](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/Secure-Hashing#shavs) and SHA-256 value of empty string (length 0)  is given as in the file `SHA256ShortMsg.rsp`;

> ```
> Len = 0
> Msg = 00
> MD = e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
> ```

**Note 3**: For the NIST's hash function, one should not rely on the third-party result. They need to look at NIST vectors.